# num rows in single query

Tags: php

I have two tables and I want to count the number of rows in a single query.

Here is what I have so far and is working but has multiple query's and is not ok.

PHP Code:

```
     $q1=$db->query("SELECT id FROM edev_useri");
     $q2=$db->query("SELECT groupid FROM edev_useri WHERE groupid = 6");
     $q3=$db->query("SELECT groupid FROM edev_useri WHERE groupid = 7");
     $q4=$db->query("SELECT id FROM edev_cereri");
       $useri  = $db->numRows($q1);
       $dev    = $db->numRows($q2);
       $ben    = $db->numRows($q3);
       $cereri = $db->numRows($q4);
     $data=array();
     $dashStats = array(
      'useri'  => $useri,
      'dev'    => $dev,
      'ben'    => $ben,
      'cereri' => $cereri
      ); 
     $data[]=$dashStats;
     $json_data = array('dashStats' => $data); 
      echo json_encode($json_data);
```

Comment: Using `numRows` is not a good approach to begin with (because that still puts all records into the result set first), you should write queries that return a single record only, using the `COUNT()` aggregate function. And once you have done that, you can combine multiple such queries using a `UNION`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, well..as i say'd im new and if you could give me an example based on my code, will be great, thank you

Comment: This is not mysqli. What library are you using?

Comment: Is mysqli, but i have a mysqli class that i have write functions with my desired names

Comment: Then it's not mysqli you are asking about, is it? What exactly is your question? It's not clear what outcome you expect.

Comment: Is mysqli, the $db->query is mysqli_query and $db->numRows is mysqli_num_rows , instead of use mysqli_query i use query , what i'm missing?

Comment: What does it mean "num rows in single query"? Also, why are you using `mysqli_num_rows` instead of counting the data in SQL?

Comment: as i say numRows is actually mysqli_num_rows

Comment: _"as i say'd im new and if you could give me an example based on my code"_ - you have been given a couple of keywords, so _you_ go and research them first of all now, please, if they are still unknown to you. Make an attempt, and then report back if you run into a problem, or still have _specific_ questions.

Comment: Please explain what is it that you are trying to achieve. Are you saying `mysqli_num_rows` doesn't give you the count of rows returned in each result set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not pretty, and perhaps you could do this a better way,
but it does the job.

*untested ofc*

```
SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM edev_useri) AS `useri`,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM edev_useri WHERE groupid = 6) AS `dev`,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM edev_useri WHERE groupid = 7) AS `ben`,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM edev_cereri) AS `cereri`
;
```

Answer (score 1):

*Note: It's a bit unclear what the actual problem is, but from what I understood, it's about reducing this to one SQL query only. This means that it requires a different query, so this answer is talking about ways to do it in SQL. How to interpret the different results in PHP is not covered.*

You can use `COUNT(*)` (returning the count of rows as single value) and `UNION SELECT` (allowing you to combine multiple `SELECT`s in one, as long as the number of columns is the same in all of them):

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM edev_useri
UNION SELECT COUNT(*) FROM edev_useri WHERE groupid = 6
UNION SELECT COUNT(*) FROM edev_useri WHERE groupid = 7
UNION SELECT COUNT(*) FROM edev_cereri
```

Then you get a result like this:

```
+-----+
|count|
+-----+
|    1|
|    2|
|    3|
|    4|
+-----+
```

Or you could use `SUM` to count all the three things related to `edev_useri` in one row:

```sql
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS `count`,
  COALESCE(SUM(groupid = 6), 0) AS `group6Count`
  COALESCE(SUM(groupid = 7), 0) AS `group7Count`
FROM edev_useri
UNION SELECT COUNT(*), NULL, NULL FROM edev_cereri
```

(This works because `groupid = 6` will evaluate to `1` when the condition is true, so the `SUM` of all those `1`s will equal to the count of rows matching the condition. The extra `COALESCE` is used just so that in case all rows have `groupid` as `NULL` - or there are no rows - the result would still be `0` and not `NULL`.)

Then you get a result like this:

```
+-----+-----------+-----------+
|count|group6Count|group7Count|
+-----+-----------+-----------+
|    1|          2|          3|
|    4|       NULL|       NULL|
+-----+-----------+-----------+
```

Or, if you prefer it all in one row, you can do the 4th item as subquery:

```sql
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS `userCount`,
  COALESCE(SUM(groupid = 6), 0) AS `group6Count`,
  COALESCE(SUM(groupid = 7), 0) AS `group7Count`,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM edev_cereri) AS `requestCount`
FROM edev_useri
```

Then you get a result like this:

```
+-----+-----------+-----------+------------+
|count|group6Count|group7Count|requestCount|
+-----+-----------+-----------+------------+
|    1|          2|          3|           4|
+-----+-----------+-----------+------------+
```